# Load external font in webpage. Solution for Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, font-face

In all decent webbrowsers @font-face just works for loading an external font into your webpage. However, for IE versions older than IE9 this does not work. I'd like to use the Ubuntu Font Family.
Any brilliant ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) will create the proper cross-browser CSS for you.

Example CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DroidSansRegular';
    src: url('/resources/fonts/DroidSans-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/resources/fonts/DroidSans-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/resources/fonts/DroidSans-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/resources/fonts/DroidSans-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/resources/fonts/DroidSans-webfont.svg#DroidSansRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

This works in IE7 and above and, of course, all other browsers.

Comment: Yeah... great CSS file... `/* Generated by Font Squirrel (http://www.fontsquirrel.com) on August 9, 2011 */`, that's everything inside the generated CSS file.

Comment: Tried it again, and this time it **did** work :D Going to test it now.

Comment: Still no Ubuntu font to be seen on the page :s

Comment: I'm talking about this page. http://www.heuvel-folie-serres.com/Veestal_v2/?pagina=home It includes the generated CSS file if the website is opened with Internet Explorer.

Comment: @RobinJ: You have 2 font-family declarations in the body CSS tag. It is working in IE9 on my PC. Try clearing your cache.

Comment: ... @font-face always works in IE9... The problem is IE8 and IE7.

Comment: Apparently it **did** work... Only on the Windows machine I tested it on (not mine) the font appeared so pixely that I didn't even recognise it >.<

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at [this article](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/becoming-a-font-embedding-master):

> **Browser Support**
>
> Which leads me into the other major issue, browser support. Font
>   embedding with a TrueType or OpenType font only works as of Firefox
>   3.5, Safari 3.1, and Opera 10. (You can enable it in your copy of
>   Chrome 2 by using a command line switch.)
>
> Okay, that's decent already but we can do better. We can get Internet
>   Explorer 4+, Chrome 0.3+, Opera 9+ and even a little mobile Safari
>   action. EOT
>
> Internet Explorer supports a particular type of format called Embedded
>   OpenType that provides some control over where and how the font is
>   allowed to be embedded. You'll need to convert your TTF into an EOT
>   format. Microsoft provides a tool called WEFT but it is ancient and
>   I'll be damned if I can get it working. Thankfully, there is a command
>   line tool called TTF2EOT that can convert your font.

Also: [How do I load external fonts into an HTML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237540/how-do-i-load-external-fonts-into-an-html-document)