# Load external font with javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fonts

I have a < p > element created dynamically with jquery, and I want to style it with a custom font that I have on my hard drive.

Could you sugest me a method to load that font and apply it to this element.

Right now, the object looks something like:

```
$("<p>").css({ fontFamily : "Arial",
               fontSize: "13px",
               color: "#000"});
```

I want to replace fontFamily : "Arial" with my custom font.

Thanks,
Gabriel

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This piece of code does all the job:

```
$("head").prepend("<style type=\"text/css\">" + 
                                "@font-face {\n" +
                                    "\tfont-family: \"myFont\";\n" + 
                                    "\tsrc: local('☺'), url('myFont.otf') format('opentype');\n" + 
                                "}\n" + 
                                    "\tp.myClass {\n" + 
                                    "\tfont-family: myFont !important;\n" + 
                                "}\n" + 
                            "</style>");
```

Comment: Here's a simplified version. Modify as required.
    `$("head").prepend("<style>@font-face {font-family: 'customFont';src: url('file:///" + fontfile + "');}</style>");`
    `$("#url").css("font-family", "customFont");`

Answer (score 4):

I found a good solution using fontface plugin for jquery.
http://www.sitepoint.com/the-fontface-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add some CSS to your style sheet - You can find the right CSSS to add here: [How do I load external fonts into an HTML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237540/how-do-i-load-external-fonts-into-an-html-document)

You can then change the font name with whatever its called eg:

```
$("<p>").css({ fontFamily : "Kimberley",
               fontSize: "13px",
               color: "#000"});
```

**EDIT:** What would be better is to add a class in your stylesheet for the

tag and then add that class to to your p with jquery

```
p.example{ font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

$("<p>").addClass("example");
```

Comment: There will be no stylesheet. Everything will be in this .js file.

Comment: its not the answer of what he asked.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use cufon.

Works on 99% of browsers out there!

http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Enjoy!