# How to force Firefox to use first font in font-family list?

Tags: firefox, font-family

I have such problem: in all browsers font is what I want - "Helvetica Neue", but Firefox use second font in font-family list.

I checked it in Firebug:

```
      /rule from Bootstrap.scss/
      p → "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
      parent matched//
```

Here is screenshot of what I have in Firefox:

[image]

And in Chrome:

[image]

or my font is not valid for Firefox ?

Answer (score 1):

The whole reason for `font-family` list of font types is that if the client machine/browser doesn't have the first font on the list available, it will use the second, and if the second is not available it will use the third.

**EDIT**:

If you really must use the font family you want, you will need to get the font file for it and load it. here is a link to the thread that discusses this:

[How do I load external fonts into an HTML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237540/how-do-i-load-external-fonts-into-an-html-document)

Comment: ok, I asked wrongly HOW to make Firefox use "Helvetica Neue" ?

Comment: ok, I have font on my computer - maybe Firefox don't want to apply my font, because it is not correct ?

Comment: It is impossible to say why it is not loaded in Firefox without running some tests. I'd suggest to try to load it manually with CSS and see if it fixes it.