# how to load .ttf fonts from a URL path?

Tags: css, fonts

I am trying to load an external `.ttf` font in a page from a `URL path`.

it will work fine if i load it locally like so:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myFnt';
         url('fonts/Font.ttf') format('truetype'),

}
```

but it doesn't work  in `Firefox` and it doesn't load the font if I try to load like so:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myFnt';
         url('http://www.mywebsite.com/fonts/Font.ttf') format('truetype'),

}
```

I tested it in `Google Chrome` and it worked fine either way but it doesn't load the font in `Firefox` if I do it the way shown in the second code!

could someone help me out with this please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237540/how-do-i-load-external-fonts-into-an-html-document

Comment: @karthikr, nope! unfortunately that didn't help at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for 4 in chrome and firefox as well

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myFnt';
    src: url('webfonts/name.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

are you using a .htaccess file? If yes put theae on your .htaccess file

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

here you can read the solution [font-face not working only firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie)

Comment: are you using a .htaccess file??

Comment: I am using htaccess file but I need to load the font in an ebay template so .htaccess won't help!