# Including Font in HTML with <span style>

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm trying to include a font in my HTML code, but I'm not able to do it. The font is this one:

[image: Font and subfonts installed on my PC]

It has several "sub-fonts", and I want to choose between them, but I'm not able idk why. Other fonts that also has "sub-fonts" work as expected, eventhough I cannot choose between "sub-fonts"

I wrote the following code to test:
`lang=html"<span style="font-family:Formula1 Display-Regular; font-size:2em">Safety Car</span>`

First of all I wanna know if it is possible to put the font without using CSS. The second is, how am I supposed to do it (using HTML if possible, and also CSS?

Comment: you have to use @font-face on your css

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I load external fonts into an HTML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237540/how-do-i-load-external-fonts-into-an-html-document)

Answer (score 0):

Use `@font-face` and it will work as you expected. Check for typo in font-name make sure to use correct punctuations.

```css
@font-face{
    font-family:"formula1-display-regular";
    src:url("https://candyfonts.com/wp-data/2018/10/26/11543/Formula1-Regular_web_0.ttf") format("woff"),
    url("https://candyfonts.com/wp-data/2018/10/26/11543/Formula1-Regular_web_0.ttf") format("opentype"),
    url("https://candyfonts.com/wp-data/2018/10/26/11543/Formula1-Regular_web_0.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

```html
<span style="font-family:formula1-display-regular;font-size:2em">Safety Car</span>
```

Codepen [link](https://codepen.io/Ev1ltw1n/pen/ZEyZEYO)

PS: This snippet might not work here, but will work on the above codepen link.

Answer (score 0):

When you use external fonts in your web development you have to Import that font in your **CSS** file. But sometimes **CDN**  links are not available for some fonts. So in that case you have to use the `@font-face` property to use that font and import that font from local files.
I have provided `@font-face` **CSS** for formula1 font. So you have followed some steps.

1. Copy this `@font-face`  CSS code which I provided below and paste it into your CSS file.
2. After that visit this [Website](https://candyfonts.com/font/formula1-display-regular.htm) and download **.ttf** file, add this file to your project folder.
3. Now you can use the external font.

A. For more details about `@font-face` property [Click here Now](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)
B. And for **Video** tutorial [Click here Now](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzqQXDbDvus)

**Note: Please make sure that your file path is correct**

```css
@font-face{
    font-family:"formula1-display-regular";
    src:url("https://candyfonts.com/wp-data/2018/10/26/11543/Formula1-Regular_web_0.ttf") format("woff"),
    url("https://candyfonts.com/wp-data/2018/10/26/11543/Formula1-Regular_web_0.ttf") format("opentype"),
    url("https://candyfonts.com/wp-data/2018/10/26/11543/Formula1-Regular_web_0.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

Comment: @LuismiCarmona why did you remove approval of my answer.